# Spring Boot redirection to https

Tags: tomcat, ssl, browser, spring-boot, centos

I use centos 7, spring boot (who use tomcat embedded)

In my application.properties

```
security.require-ssl=true
server.port: 8443
```

I can access my web site via

```
www.xxxx.com
```

but

```
xxxx.com
```

don't work

I tried also

In my application.properties

```
server.port: 8443
```

In the Application class

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat
            = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
}

private Connector createHttpConnector() {
    Connector connector
            = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
    return connector;
}
```

In the log i see

```
s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https) 8080 (http)
```

www.xxxxx.com is working

xxxx.com is automatically converted to

xxxx.com:8443

i don't understand why the port is added.

Comment: That configuration is pretty much useless as you are creating your own container and connector. So adding anything related to the server in your `application.properties` isn't going to work anymore.

Comment: in the doc:  It’s recommended to use application.properties to configure HTTPS as the HTTP connector is the easier of the two to configure programmatically

Comment: And that relates to your question and my comment in which way? You are basically ignoring spring boot (as you create your own embedded container) and still expect the properties to apply... That is never going to happen

Comment: that happen, that the point... it's just a fact

Comment: I still don't see what you mean and how it is related. It doesn't make sense what you wrote in your comment.

Comment: just try to concentrate on the why port is added to the url.... that the important point.... dont have choice to create own embedded container to support http and https... doc say it.

Comment: why because that is what spring security does, and you haven't configured your reverse proxy to fix it.

Comment: and it's supposed to be done where? java, config file, firewall, iptables

Comment: That is too broad to answer as that would require initiate knowledge about your infrastructure and components.

Answer (score 0):

Probably disabling this directive you can avoid port redirection :

```
connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
```

But you have to consider that it makes sense with the other settings as well.